# Space in html can't find it. Safari vs IE & Firefeox

Tags: html, firefox, safari

I'm working on a website and in Safari it looks perfect (I Work on Mac).
In firefox and IE it isn't looking good.

http://www.d-votion.be/djnobels/djgentux/index.html

Could someone help me?

Greetings,

Nico

Comment: How to fix it.. I don't know what is wrong in the code.

Comment: Problem in page can't find it.

Comment: No, please tell us what you consider wrong with the FF/IE representation.

Comment: Looks pretty spiffy to me under FF/Ubuntu. Should I let the JavaScript run?

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are talking about.

To fix your code:

**Get rid of the tables, remember [CSS](http://www.csszengarden.com/) is your friend**

Answer (score 1):

- Don't [abuse tables for layout](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/)
- Do use [error checking tools](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.d-votion.be%2Fdjnobels%2Fdjgentux%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Opera has [a good introductory tutorial](http://wsc.opera.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at it in firefox 3.5.6 under windows 7 and I don't see anything wrong with it.  Could you be more specific with the problem that's occurring though?  It's hard tell what space problem your referring too.

On a more general note, if your going to be doing web development you had best be ready to have your site look different in different browsers.  It's something we all have to deal with.